# What kind of gps battery can I use for uBlox NEO-M8N GPS module?

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, gps, charge

What kind of gps battery can I use for uBlox NEO-M8N GPS module?  Would you please recommend gps battery? and Which can I use 5.5mAh or 11mAh?For example;

1. MS621FE-FL11E - BATTERY LITTIUM 3V 5.5MAH (https://ozdisan.com/bataryalar/sarj-edilebilir-piller/lityum-piller/MS621FE-FL11E)
2. Seiko MS920SE-FL27E Lithium ion Şarjlı Pil / 3.0V 11 Mah (https://birikimpilleri.net/endustriyel-piller/lithium-ion-buton/920/prd-seiko-ms920se-fl27e-lithium-pil)

If you know better please recommend to me..thanks

Comment: what does the uBlox NEO-M8N GPS module require?

Comment: there is really not such a thing as a GPS battery

Comment: GPS actually uses a lot of power. Tiny batteries like that will not last very long. Maybe 30 minutes or something. One hour.

Comment: There are two kinds of batteries, one for powering the module, another to keep config and GPS data.

Comment: @tlfong01 oh, so it can maintain the ephemeris and avoid cold start? That seems pretty smart.

Comment: @mkeith, Ha yes, let me write up an answer and show you the photos later. Stay tuned. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Question***

*What kind of power source should I use for the uBlox NEO-M8N GPS module?*

---

***Answer***

1. uBlox NEO-6/7/8M GPS Module has a small button battery on board to hold the config/fix data.
2. You need an external power source for the module.

---

*Neo-6/7/8M GPS Module Setup Example 1*

I am using bench top 220VAC to 12VDC and a LM2956 12VDC to 5VDC step down 2A PSU to power the GPS module.  I also tried Lipo 18650 batteries but found them not necessary to improve any performance.

The GPS module has a small on board button battery at the top left corner of the module.

---

[image: gps_batteries]

---

*Neo-6/7/8M GPS Module Setup Example 2*

The photo shows the small button battery at the bottom left corner.

---

[image: neo battery]

---

See the reference below for more details

---

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***References***

(1) [Rpi Neo-6M / Neo-8M GPS Module Setup / Fix / Update Problems](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113544/rpi-neo-6m-neo-8m-gps-module-setup-fix-update-problems/113601#113601)

(2) [How can Rpi listen to a GPS module? - RpiSE 2020jun02](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113057/how-can-rpi-listen-to-a-gps-module)

(3) [GPS taking long time to fix out in the open - EESE 2020sep03](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/519711/gps-taking-long-time-to-fix-out-in-the-open)

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***Appendices***

*/ to continue, ...*

---

Comment: @tlfong1 Yeah right, what I meant was button batteries. Can you give an example which type of coin button battery should I use?

Comment: Ah, u-Blox makes NEO-8, but there are a couple of vendors like SunFounder and SparkFun assemble NEO's and sell modules with difference kinds of batteries. So you need to read the user manual of your module to check out which batteries they are using. Cheers..

Answer (score 1):

4.2 Table 11 ought to imply how short a 5mAh battery will last at 25 to 32 mA @ 3V
Perhaps bigger is better. e.g. 3000mAh secondary with CMOS LDO

https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/NEO-M8-FW3_DataSheet_UBX-15031086.pdf